# Use walrus operator when checking value

Tags: python-3.8, walrus-operator

How can I check if a variable is equal to something, and set to a new variable in the child scope?

For example:

```
bar = 'foobar'
my_slice = bar[:3]
if my_slice == 'foo':
   print(my_slice)
```

It seems like the new walrus operator here would be useful, but it's not immediately straightforward how you'd go about using it here

Answer (score 0):

Walrus operators work here very well, we just need to understand exactly how they work.

```
if (my_slice := bar[3:]) == 'foo':
   print(my_slice)
```

Walrus operators set a variable to the output of some expression. It's almost identical to the equal sign in function except it can be used inline.

So this expression:

`(my_slice := bar[3:]) == 'foo'`

Can be boiled down to `(variable = expression) == value`

So because the output of `my_slice := bar[:3]` is equal to `bar[:3]`, the above is equivalent to

`bar[3:] == 'foo'`

**Note:** The parenthesis here are required, or else `variable` is going to equal the output of the comparison operation, i.e. True or False